# How to log time millis the job is started and finished

Tags: linux, bash

I can measure the job execution time with the `time` command. And the output will be like something like that:

```
real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s
```

But I would like to log the time (with millis accuracy) the job is started and finished.

Like

```
2018-01-31 22:54:57,558 started
2018-01-31 22:54:57,856 finished
```

Is it possible to do something like that in linux?

Comment: With GNU date and with nanoseconds accuracy: `date "+%F %X,%N"`

Comment: ...though it'll take a whole lot of nanoseconds (milliseconds, even) to fork a shell for, link, load and execute that copy of GNU date -- enough, I'd argue, to make the precision effectively meaningless. Modern bash's printf `%(...)T` construct has far less overhead, but doesn't support more than second resolution; so if you *truly* need precision (1) you shouldn't be using bash; and (2) writing a loadable module in C for the shell is an appropriate action.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU date:

```
date "+%F %X,%N started" | cut -c 1-23,30-
```

Output:

```
2018-02-05 01:55:59,217 started
```